# Set playframework version 1.2.7 to 1.3

Tags: playframework, configuration-files

How do I change the version of Play my PAAS service will deploy?

Is this something that is set in the application.conf or perhaps system.properties

My app automatically deploys with Play 1.2.7 on a PAAS service I'm using (not Heroku). Instead I want the app to deploy with version 1.3 (because I need to use Java 8).

Locally I run Play 1.3 and that gives no errors with Java 8.

Comment: You need to provide more info about the service you are using. From here it seems the problem is there

Comment: Ok will ask them and report back with results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to modify the dependencies.yml file

It should look like this:

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play 1.3.1
```